# How to calculate the average time it takes to get to a value given an array of values

Tags: probability

Im sorry if this is a confusing question. I'm terrible at math so please let me know if I need to elaborate on anything.

I have an array of values `V`

I have a target value that I would like to hit `T`

There are `N` "cycles" that happen where a random number is picked from `V` and added to the total amount. What is the average (`A`) number of times we hit `T`.

For example:

```
V = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
N = 10
T = 100
A = ???
```

So, to explain. I have 10 random picks from my array `V`. On average, how likely am I that my 10 picks will >= `T`

Again, Im so sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Do you know about generating functions?

Comment: @saulspatz I don't. Any links?

Comment: @devza Here is a source from Brilliant: https://brilliant.org/wiki/generating-functions-solving-recurrence-relations/.

Comment: I'll write an answer and explain.

Comment: @saulspatz is the answer $\frac{\sum_{j \geq T}{c_j}}{|V|^N}$ where $c_j$ is the coefficient of $x^j$ in $\Big(\sum_{v \in V}x^v\Big)^N$? I literally just learned about generating functions from this post and I'm curious to see if my answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this without a bunch of calculation.  The first thing to notice is that it's very unlikely that we won't reach $100$ in $10$ trials; even if we pick $8$ every time, we get close.  So it will be easy to calculate the probability that we don't reach $100$ and subtract from $1$.

Consider the expression $$p(x)=(x^8+x^9+\cdots+x^{19}+x^{20})^{10}$$ For any sequence of $10$ picks, take the terms in the $10$ factors corresponding to the picks and multiply them.  That is, if the first pick is $11$ we take $x^{11}$ from the first factor.  If the second pick is $14$, we take $x^{14}$ from the second factor.  In the product, the coefficient of any term $x^k$ is the number of ways to get a sum of $k$.

Now $$\begin{align}p(x)&=x^{80}(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{12})^{10}\\&=x^{80}\frac{(x^{13}-1)^{10}}{(x-1)^{10}}\\&=(x^{13}-1)^{10}(x-1)^{-10}\\
&=x^{80}(x^{13}-1)^{10}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{-10}{k}x^k\\
&=x^{80}(x^{13}-1)^{10}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+9}{k}
\end{align}$$ by the binomial theorem.
Now of course, we could expand the product and pick out the terms of degree less than $100$ manually, but I used a CAS at this point.  Notice that we don't really need an infinite sum,  We can cut it off at $k=19$, since we are only interest in terms of degree less than $100.$

```
from sympy import binomial, Symbol

x = Symbol('x')

p = sum(binomial(9+k,k)*x**k for k in range(20)).as_poly()
q = ((x**3-1)**10).as_poly()
r = p*q
a = r.coeffs()[-20:]
print(a)
print(1-sum(a)/13**10)
print(float(1-sum(a)/13**10))

from random import choices

trials = 1000000
count = 0
pop = list(range(8,21))
for _ in range(trials):
    c = choices(pop, k=10)
    count += sum(c) >= 100
print(count/trials)
```

This produced the output

```
[10, 55, 210, 615, 1452, 2850, 4740, 6765, 8350, 8953, 8350, 6765, 4740, 2850, 1452, 615, 210, 55, 10, 1]
137858432801/137858491849
0.9999995716767301
0.999857
```

Sympy write the coefficients in order of significance, so that $1$ is the coefficient of $x^{80}$, $10$ the coefficient of $x^{81}$ and so on.  You can check the first few and see that they are correct.  The exact probability is $$\frac{137858432801}{137858491849}\approx .9999995716767301$$

I also simulated $1,000,000$ drawings, with $999,857$ successes.

Comment: So as someone who is completely new to this, a lot of this doesnt make sense. Saying that, you've given me enough to break down piece by piece and learn.

Thanks :)

Comment: @devza If you have specific questions, I'll try to answer them.

Comment: Is the line where you are adding the binomials correct? Should that range not be range(7,20)? Who do you do it from 0 - 20?

Comment: My 2nd question is how do I manipulate this for say, 6 picks?

Comment: @devza First question: I pulled out a factor of $x^{80}$.  Second question: If there were $6$ picks, the exponent would be $6$ instead of $10$.  This is the essential point in understanding the method.